# how to get HSV value from image

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv, image-conversion

I try to get the value of each channel in HSV ,RGB and YCrCb 
I dont know if my anwser is true or false .what is the range of any channel

```
        Mat orig = new Mat(@"D:\more-pic\m1.jpg", ImreadModes.Color);
        pictureBox1.Image = orig.Bitmap;
        Image<Bgr, byte> finalimg = new Image<Bgr, byte>(orig.Width, orig.Height);
          Image<Bgr, byte> finalimg1 = new Image<Bgr, byte>(orig.Width,    orig.Height);
           using (Mat hsv = new Mat())
           {
            CvInvoke.CvtColor(orig, hsv, ColorConversion.Bgr2Hsv);
            hsv.CopyTo(finalimg);
            pictureBox2.Image = finalimg.Bitmap;
            Mat[] channels = hsv.Split();

            RangeF H = channels[0].GetValueRange();
            RangeF S = channels[1].GetValueRange();
            RangeF V = channels[2].GetValueRange();
            label1.Text = "H.Min: " + H.Min.ToString();
            label2.Text = "S.Min: " + S.Min.ToString();
            label3.Text = "V.Min: " + V.Min.ToString();

            label4.Text = "H.Max: " + H.Max.ToString();
            label5.Text = "S.Max: " + S.Max.ToString();
            label6.Text = "V.Max: " + V.Max.ToString();
```

Comment: Please tag the programming language you’re using.

Comment: Is this C# or something *"Windows-y"*?

Comment: This would be C# judging from the syntax and also the OP has tagged EmguCV.  I'm adding the C# tag.